# Code that checks if a words from string is a palindrome. Can't recognize words at the end of the phrase

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define NMAX 1000

int main()
{
    char line[NMAX];
    int palindromo = 1;

    FILE*fp;

    fp=fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if(fp != NULL){
        while(fgets(line, NMAX, fp)){

            char*word = strtok(line, " ");
            while(word != NULL){

                palindromo = 1;

                int lunghezza = strlen(word);

                if((lunghezza>0) && (word[lunghezza-1] == '\n')){
                    word[lunghezza-1] = '\0';
                }


                for(int i=0; i<lunghezza; i++){
                    word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
                }


                for(int i=0; i<lunghezza/2; i++){
                    if(word[i] != word[lunghezza-1-i]){
                        palindromo = 0;
                    }

                }

                if(palindromo == 1){
                    for(int i=0; i<lunghezza; i++){
                        word[i] = toupper(word[i]);
                    }
                }

                puts(word);

                word = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

the input file is this:

```
Anna ha preso otto a scuola. la mamma le ha regalato una spilla in oro e le ha organizzato un giro in kayak
Anche il cane ha avuto in premio un osso lo ha mangiato come un ossesso.
```

The only words that the program is not recognizing as palindrome are kayak and ossesso (both at the end of the strings).

Sry the code and the input.txt file are in italian.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted by @RobMayoff, you must account for shortening the length of the last word in the buffer.

You could save yourself grief and code by using `" \n"` as the delimiter in both calls to `strtok()`. The function would *clobber* both the SP and newline characters delivering back pointers to individual words.

```
word = strtok( line, " \n" );
```

In so doing, you eliminate some of your code (that happened to have a bug.)

---

To avoid the opportunity of a future bug by having two separate invocations of `strtok()`, the operation could be rewritten in one line:

```
for( char *word = line; (word = strtok( word, " \n" ) ) != NULL; word = NULL )
```

Think your way through this `for()` loop and see why it works.

Less code (that works) is better.

Comment: WOW, thank you, I was wondering if i could add more than one delimeter in the strtok function. That is brilliant, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When `word[lunghezza-1] == '\n'`, you replace the `\n` with `\0`. You also need to reduce `lunghezza` by 1.

```
                if((lunghezza>0) && (word[lunghezza-1] == '\n')){
                    word[lunghezza-1] = '\0';
                    --lunghezza;
                }
```

Comment: Oh Yes, you are right, otherwise the check for palindrome will not work. Thank you so much.